# JBoss as7 to WildFly migration EJB Invocation failed

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly

I try to migrate from JBoss AS 7 to Wildfly 8.2. and i get the EJB Invocation failed error message:

```
14:06:07,692 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 125) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component SettingService for method public com.mycompany.myapp.server.db.entity.Setting com.mycompany.myapp.server.business.setting.SettingService.getSetting(com.mycompany.myapp.server.db.entity.Setting$ParameterName): javax.ejb.EJBAccessException:  JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public com.mycompany.myapp.server.db.entity.Setting com.mycompany.myapp.server.business.setting.SettingService.getSetting(com.mycompany.myapp.server.db.entity.Setting $ParameterName) of bean: SettingService is not allowed
      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:135) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
      at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448)
      at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
      at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
      at com.mycompany.myapp.server.business.setting.SettingService$$$view329.getSetting(Unknown Source) [com.mycompany.myapp.server.business-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:414) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
      at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
      at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
      at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:65) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
      at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
      at com.mycompany.myapp.server.business.setting.SettingService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.getSetting(Unknown Source) [com.mycompany.myapp.server.business-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
      at com.mycompany.myapp.server.batch.common.BatchScheduler.firstInit(BatchScheduler.java:58) [com.mycompany.myapp.server.batch-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:96)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doLifecycleInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:114) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:103) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
      at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
      at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:53) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:109)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.java:94) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:369) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:66) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
      at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
      at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
      at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:160)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:133)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:89)
      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:122) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:137) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

After hours of debuging i'm pretty sure the problem must be in my jboss-ejb3.xml file.

But i can't find any working version of this file. All the examples on the wildfly page generate some errors...

My file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss:ejb-jar
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:s="urn:security:1.1"
    version="3.1" impl-version="2.0">

    <assembly-descriptor>
        <s:security>
            <!-- Even wildcard * is supported -->
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <!-- Name of the security domain which is configured in the EJB3 subsystem -->
            <s:security-domain>auraRealm</s:security-domain>
        </s:security>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

Does anyone have a working example of this file?

Comment: Not actually, But I think looking at tutorials on www.mastertheboss.com may come handy for you.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code/classes to your post?

Comment: That doesn't help to resolve the problem, because the error occurs on every bean. The application is started and deployed without errors, and as soon a bean is called the error occurs. The same application works fine on JBoss as 7 so i don't think there is something wrong with my code. The error must be somewhere in the new settings but i have no idea where...

Comment: I found the answer by this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151279/security-exceptions-when-injecting-an-ejb-in-wildfly